# NGINX + ExpressJS - Reverse proxy for URLs in HTML

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have a NodeJS + ExpressJS app running on port 3000 which has a route:

```
router.get('/getHello', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello, world!');
});
```

and a HTML page which does a GET on this route

```
<a href="/getHello">
    <input type="button" value="Visit Helo World page" />
</a>
```

This standalone app works as intended. It displays `Hello, world!` when the button is pressed.

**Now, here's the problem:**

I have setup a reverse proxy on this app using `nginx`. Here's the config file from `sites-available` (linked with `sites-enabled`)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /routetest/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

The app opens fine when I visit `http://localhost/routetest` but when I click on the button, it opens `http://localhost/getHello` whereas I wanted it to open `http://localhost/routetest/getHello`. Since `http://localhost/getHello` is not defined, I end up with a 404. (On the other hand, `http://localhost/routetest/getHello` correctly returns the `Hello, world` message)

**Now, my question is:**

My frontend is written with `/` as the base path (to make all GET and POST requests), for example `<a href="/getHello">` and I feel manually **appending** `/routetest/` before all URLs in my HTML not a good practice (since I may want to change this base path later and then I'll have to update it everywhere). So, is there a way for `NGINX` or some `express` middleware to add `/routetest/` for URLs that are written with `/` as the base path, without having to change it in my HTML manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By a long way the easiest solution is to use relative paths without the leading `/` if that's an option that's available to you.

Rewriting URLs in the response is somewhere between tricky and impossible in the general case. If you think you can successfully identify the relevant URLs in your content you might be able to use nginx's catchily titled `ngx_http_sub_module`:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html

There are various Express middleware implementations that do a similar thing but I couldn't find one that looked reliable enough to recommend. The basic approach would be similar to the `compression` middleware if you fancy giving it a go yourself. Again it's quite difficult in general but depending on the specifics of how you serve up your HTML it might not be too bad.

Comment: Removing the leading `/` works and I agree that it's the simplest solution, but still requires me to modify all URLs. I don't know why I didn't think of relative URLs while working on the front end. Is it a good practice to have relative URLs? Any downsides?

Comment: Identifying all the URLs to modify is indeed a tricky task as you said, but I'll try it with `ngx_http_sub_module` nevertheless.

Comment: @Abhilashk I'd generally use relative URLs but they also have problems. e.g. If you have a shared page header that references some CSS but the pages aren't all in the same place relative to that CSS. I suppose some `<base>` trickery might help with that but I've never gone down that route myself. I imagine most of the URLs in your HTML are of the form `href="/`, `src="/` or `action="/`, which may not be too bad. For JS it'll either be trivial or a nightmare depending on the specifics.